# How can I tell if I'm on a custom post type archive page?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, custom-taxonomy, archives

I have set up a custom post type and a custom taxonomy for it. I'm using the latest version of Wordpress. I believe I should be using the `is_post_type_archive` function, but this seems to be is returning false no matter what.

The post type I've set up is called `articles` and the taxonomy is called `editions`

I'm trying to access `/editions/september` and the archive page is showing, but the page title is showing as the first post's title. I can fix this if I can figure out how to write a conditional if statement to let me know I am in a custom post type custom taxonomy page. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure your CPT is using the `'has_archive' => true,` parameter? 
And try something like;

```
wp_reset_query(); 

 if (is_post_type_archive('articles')){
     // do something
    }
```